# How can I create a BackGround service that runs a function every given period of time ? Using C# (asp.net core 3.1.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service

I'm trying to make call to a function every specified interval of time, for that m using Background service, here is what I have done:
Here is the Alerting controller where I have the function:

```
public class AlertingController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AlertingController(DatabaseContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
    }
    public AlertingController()
    {

    }
//function that adds in the DB
    public async Task<AlertingResponse> GetAlertingToDB()
    {
        AlertingResponse dataGet;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient
                .GetAsync(MetricApiLink))
            {
                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dataGet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlertingResponse>(apiResponse);
            }
        }
        if (dataGet.data.alerts != null || dataGet.data.alerts.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var alert in dataGet.data.alerts)
            {
                CreateAlertQuery QueryAlert = new CreateAlertQuery();
                QueryAlert.Name = alert.labels.alertname;
                QueryAlert.Instance = alert.labels.instance;
                QueryAlert.Serverity = alert.labels.severity;
                QueryAlert.Summary = alert.annotations.summary;
                QueryAlert.State = alert.state;
                QueryAlert.ActiveAt = alert.activeAt;
                var _Alert = _mapper.Map<AlertingDataModel>(QueryAlert);
                _context.Alertings.Add(_Alert);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I have tested the method with a HTTPGET request, it works fine, add the alerts into my database:

[image]

I have created a scooped service where I called the function `GetAlertingToDB()`:

```
    internal interface IScopedAlertingService
    {
        Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
    }
    public class ScopedAlertingService : IScopedAlertingService
    {
        private int executionCount = 0;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ScopedAlertingService(ILogger<ScopedAlertingService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        AlertingController _AlertingToDB = new AlertingController();
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            executionCount++;

            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Scoped Processing Service is working. Count: {Count}", executionCount);

            await _AlertingToDB.GetAlertingToDB();

            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also created the Class that will consume my service, and will run in the BackGround:

```
public class ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> _logger;

    public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services,
        ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> logger)
    {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service running.");

        await DoWork(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is working.");

        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedProcessingService =
                scope.ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<IScopedAlertingService>();

            await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is stopping.");

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I injected the dependencies on the Startup Class and added the hosted service:

```
        services.AddHostedService<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService>();
        services.AddScoped<IScopedAlertingService, ScopedAlertingService>();
```

The functions are working just fine untill a call the `GetAlertingToDB()` function and it doesn't work.

Any help would be great, thanks everyone :)

Comment: As I saw in the documentation they that we can run a background service along with the API, I have also watched a tutorial on youtube where someone created a project from triming vdeios etc... and used queued background services, maybe it's a good idea to run them separatelly but I prefer running the service when the application starts and shutting it down when the application shuts

Comment: @Hasagiii: Sure, you can run the background service in-proc side-by-side, but you can't directly call a controller from the background service.

Comment: Okey any ideas for this? Thanks :)

Comment: Use a Timed Background Task instead.  I have added a link with a sample of this in asp.net core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would rearrange your solution so that your background service doesn't need to create a `Controller`. Instead the controller, if you still need it at all, should call into your `ScopedAlertingService` where the work is performed once. Your background service can simply loop forever, with an `await Task.Delay()`.

```cs
    public class ScopedAlertingService : IScopedAlertingService
    {
        public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            // move contents of your AlertingController.GetAlertingToDB here
        }
    }

    public class ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
        public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            _services = services;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);

                using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedProcessingService =
                        scope.ServiceProvider
                            .GetRequiredService<IScopedAlertingService>();

                    await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I left the code as it is I just moved the function to the `DoWork()` method and it's working fine now, I'll try again doing it another way :)

Answer (score 2):

Hangfire RecurringJob would be an option for you case. you can check it here https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html.
The benefit of using it is: you have a dashboard to check when the task will be fired and the result of the task.

Comment: HangFire is based on Asp.net Framework, I'm using .net core for multiple plateform, I know there are many libraries like quartz-net etc.. But I prefer using Hosted services :)

Comment: I am using hangfire for .netcore which is deployed in ubuntu server and it works well. 
Have you checked the hangfire page, it has a sentence: "An easy way to perform background processing in .NET and **.NET Core** applications"

Comment: Yes thanks a lot a man, for now I have managed the functions it worked, your idea is very nice, I'll be using it in the futur for certain needs :D

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for doing this.

Please read the following link from the Microsoft Documentation which has several examples on how to do this in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core:

[Worker Service In NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

It is called Worker Services.

You basically implement two interfaces: IHostedService, IDisposable

Then you register your service inside you Startup class in your ConfigureServices method like this:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyCoolWorkerServiceClass>();
```

For a [Complete Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks)

One last sugestion. The example uses System.Threading.Timer... But I think it is better to use a System.Timers.Timer with AutoReset = false.

The reason is to avoid overlapping runs of your service.  Once a run is done then you start your timer again.

But then again it all depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes @Jonathan, I have seen the examples, trying to do as they say, but I can't call the function ,I guess I have to intentiate the mapper and the DB context every time I need them?

Comment: @Hasagiii  Yes but instead of creating a "Scoped Service" deriving from Background worker.  Just use Timed background tasks with a timer. Like the last link I provided... I do this all the time. I have many services that run every so many seconds etc.

Comment: @Hasagiii also why does it need to consume the Alerting service... Why not perform the work inside the Worker?

Comment: Just for the visibility of the code, I want people to understand what's happening there, do u think that I need to put some modifications there?

Comment: A couple of things I would change.  Number one you do not need the AlertingController to be an actual controller unless it is going to be called through HTTP... which it seems it is not.  Also you are creating instances of HttpClient every time GetAlertingToDB is called... this will eventually crash your service because the server will run out of connections.  Last worker services are mostly meant to be singletons NOT scoped services.